# Xaml Binding Data To RadioButton Content Working But Content Is Getting Displayed False

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, win-universal-app

The Xaml of my RadioButton:

```
  <RadioButton FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"  Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"  Content="{Binding SymbolIndex}" ></RadioButton>
```

The property window in visual studio from the "RadioButton":

[image: Binding Content is working]

The Designer is displaying this:

[image: Content is being displayed false]

Adding the Radio Button to my Observable Collection in the Code:

```
  MenueButtons.Add(new Models.SplitView.MenueButton { Description = "Home", SymbolIndex = "&#xE700;" });
```

Further information:

- It is getting displayed correctly when I type in the content propery manually

Requested Answer(s):

- What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change &#xE700 to it's unicode value: \uE700

XML uses Unicode, Xaml does as well. &#x designates the HTML encoding.